# System.AccessViolationException is thrown when adding an "Accepted-Language" to a HtmlWeb pre-request's headers

Tags: c#, uwp, html-agility-pack, access-violation

When debugging my UWP-application, it throws a **System.AccessViolationException** with the message '*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*' and the stack trace is null. The exception is thrown when trying to add an "Accept-Language" ("en-US") to the HtmlWeb object's pre-request header (see the picture and code below). Running the same code using xUnit works fine. Does someone recognize the problem?

Picture of thrown exception: https://i.stack.imgur.com/17gHB.png

```cs
public static HtmlNode GetHtmlNode(string url, string requestLanguage)
{
    var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    htmlWeb.PreRequest += (request) =>
    {
        // This line of code throws the exception (see the picture as well)
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", requestLanguage);
        return true;
    };
    return htmlWeb.Load(url).DocumentNode;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Yes, I am. Like the tag says.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the tag. Does the exception contains an InnerException? I can't reproduce the issue on my machine. Which version of .NET and the HtmlAgilityPack are you using?

Comment: I just looked, the InnerException is null, the .NET version is Standard 2.0 and the HtmlAgilityPack version is 1.11.1.

Comment: Tested your code sample (using .NET Standarad 2.0 and the HtmlAgilityPack  1.11.1), but the exception didn't occur. Perhaps you can test these two methods in a separate new project? If the exception still occurs, you may want to share the test project?

Comment: @Davuskus, The better way is that share a test project for us.

Comment: I solved the issue without really knowing what was wrong but I posted my solution if anyone is interested. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by not using HtmlWeb at all, as shown below:

```cs
public static HtmlNode GetHtmlNode(string url, string requestLanguageCode)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla";
        request.Accept = "Accept: text/html";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: " + requestLanguageCode);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            return doc.DocumentNode;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```